# Can't install Next.js with Preact

Tags: node.js, next.js, preact, npx

I'm trying to install the Next.js/Preact.js setup from vercel and I get the following error:

```
> npx create-next-app --example using-preact using-preact-app

Need to install the following packages:
  create-next-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y
Creating a new Next.js app in /home/somayyah/Documents/using-preact-app.

Downloading files for example using-preact. This might take a moment.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: using-preact@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@0.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"npm:@preact/compat@^0.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.6.0 || ^17" from next@10.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"^10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/somayyah/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/somayyah/.npm/_logs/2021-02-13T17_16_32_165Z-debug.log
```

I tried setting up Preact by myself on another project and I had the same issue, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug related to npx. i am using `yarn create next-app --example using-preact using-preact-app` and it is installed successfully but unfortunately it looks like the example is not working and throws the error `Could not find module' webpack`